# HTTP Server responding back with 200 OK without validating Host field sent in GET

Tags: curl, get

I have one BSD machine (acting as client) and Linux (acting as server, ip - 100.100.100.1) , now on server configured as follows

[root@lnx1 ~]# cat /var/www/html/index.html
LNX1 - TESTING

Now from client i am trying curl with Host name and received 200 OK

bsd1# curl -H 'Host: www.ola.com' http://"100.100.100.1"
LNX1 - TESTING
bsd1#

But on server , i haven't configured www.ola.com , how 200 OK server sent back ??

My understanding is that once server - "100.100.100.1" received GET it check for Host (i.e in my case www.ola.com on server) and if it is present then it respond back with 200 OK , but looks like my understanding is not correct , can some one guide me ??

Regards
Thanmay !!

Comment: Your webserver configuration would help clarify matters here. My guess is that you have some domain configured as the default for the IP, then the HOST header is basically ignored in favor of just returning that domain.

Answer (score 0):

The Host header field must be sent to the server,
and the server must check if it is received.
That´s all. The server may not check the validity.

To quote the standard:

> The Host request-header field specifies the Internet host and port
>   number of the resource being requested,  as obtained from the original
>   URI given by the user or referring resource   ...   The Host field
>   value MUST represent the naming authority of the origin server or
>   gateway given by the original URL.  This allows the origin server or
>   gateway to differentiate between internally-ambiguous URLs,  such as
>   the root "/" URL of a server for multiple host names on a single IP
>   address.   ...   A client MUST include a Host header field in all
>   HTTP/1.1 request messages .  If the requested URI does not include an
>   Internet host name for the service being requested,  then the Host
>   header field MUST be given with an empty value.   ...   All
>   Internet-based HTTP/1.1 servers MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request)
>   status code to any  HTTP/1.1 request message which lacks a Host header
>   field.

(parts of RFC2616, section 14.23
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

If the server has no problems with understanding which resource was meant,
it may choose to not use the Host field at all (other than checking the existence)